# Send Plain or Encrypted Password in API

Tags: laravel, api, jwt, md5, bcrypt

Previously I was using md5 for decryption but then later on I switched on to BCrypt which is a better alternative.

So Let's say I developed an API and in that there is a service for **User Log In**. I try to call this service using postman and by passing the required parameters i.e **username** and **password**.

Now, I don't know if its possible or not but what If some hacker intercepts my requests? If he can intercept it then that means he can see the plain password which I've sent in the request param, right?

What's the best thing to do here if it's possible? Do I have to pass in password encrypted in Bcrypt in the API?

P.s. I use JWT based authentication for my API's.

Comment: Use HTTPS . This is exactly what it's meant to protect from.

Comment: Okay but what if I'm on HTTP and besides my real question is do we have to send encrypted password in API request?

Comment: Being in HTTP should not be an option in (practically) the year 2020. If you are on HTTPS then **all** traffic including transmitted passwords is encrypted using proper encryption schemes that have been heavily scrutinized for this purpose. What you're doing here is essentially rolling your own encryption scheme. You must never do that.

Comment: So passing plain password in request param is a good thing right? I just have to use HTTPS

Comment: Yes if you're using HTTPS the browser will handle the encryption and the webserver the decryption. Bad actors who intercept it will only see encrypted data which are going to be near impossible to break.

Comment: Okay Thanks! I think this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: There's an answer already that is saying more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTPS instead of HTTP for your API requests. Then it is difficult or impossible for man in the middle attacks.

Always use post method instead of get or any other method to send confidential data

"Implementing the use of TLS and HTTPS would provide effective encryption and authentication of transmitted data to protect the website from Man-in-the-Middle attacks. This effectively obstructs the decryption of confidential data like authentication keys" <<  [Read More.....](https://securebox.comodo.com/ssl-sniffing/man-in-the-middle-attack/)